# Creating Json Response in java servlet

Tags: android, json, servlets

I am trying to create a `JSON` response from java `servlet`. By using some tutorial I did

```
  JSONObject json      = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray  addresses = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject address;
    try
    {
       int count = 5;

       for (int i=0 ; i<count ; i++)
       {
           address = new JSONObject();
           address.put("CustomerName"     , "Decepticons" + i);
           address.put("Street"            , "Devestator Avenue" + i);
           address.put("City"              , "Megatron City" + i);
           address.put("Country"           , "CyberTron" + i);
           addresses.add(address);
       }
       json.put("Addresses", addresses);
    }
    catch (JSONException jse)
    { 

    }
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

and the out put is

```
 {"Addresses":[{"CustomerName":"Decepticons0","Street":"Devestator Avenue0","City":"Megatron City0","Country":"CyberTron0"},{"CustomerName":"Decepticons1","Street":"Devestator Avenue1","City":"Megatron City1","Country":"CyberTron1"},{"CustomerName":"Decepticons2","Street":"Devestator Avenue2","City":"Megatron City2","Country":"CyberTron2"},{"CustomerName":"Decepticons3","Street":"Devestator Avenue3","City":"Megatron City3","Country":"CyberTron3"},{"CustomerName":"Decepticons4","Street":"Devestator Avenue4","City":"Megatron City4","Country":"CyberTron4"}]}
```

the problem is when when i try to parse this into my android application it showing a error as

Error parsing data `org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Apache of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

am using android code json parsing example from
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

can any one solve my problem?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your server response is not  a `json`, have you tried to log `json = sb.toString();`?

Comment: i checked with http://jsonlint.com/ saying that was validate json

Comment: It looks like your server (or some server in the middle) is ignoring your JSON and returning HTML to your client, most likely an error page. Copy the exact URL that your app users and paste it into your browser (or `curl`), see what it turns up.

Comment: @Kstar Of course, but in this case it will be better to `log.d(json);` to check the whole response. i am sure it is an `<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/x.x.xx - Error report</title>.`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
json.toJSONString()
```

instead of

```
json.toString()
```

Comment: it seems there is no json.toJSONString() predefined function. error say's -The method toJSONString() is undefined for the type JSONObject